# How do I create a random 4 digit number in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table of several hundred users and I want to create a 4-digit pin code like those used at an ATM machine for each user using an UPDATE statement. They don't have to be unique, but I don't want to use an autonumber type of field so one company cannot easily guess the pin code of another user. What is the simplest and easiest way to do this?

Note: This pin code is used as another layer of authentication, they also need a password to login.

Comment: Both of these works for me. Thanks to everyone for your help!

UPDATE users
SET `pin_code` = LPAD(FLOOR(RAND()*10000), 4, '0');

UPDATE users
SET `pin_code` = (select floor(0+ RAND() * 10000));
-- * After setting the zerofill option

Comment: That's not technically two-factor It only tests what the user *knows*, not what the user *has* or what the user *is*. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-factor_authentication

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the [Mysql docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand)...

To obtain a random integer R in the range i <= R < j, use the expression FLOOR(i + RAND() * (j – i)). For example, to obtain a random integer in the range the range 7 <= R < 12, you could use the following statement:

SELECT FLOOR(7 + (RAND() * 5));

```
update user set pin=(select floor(0+ RAND() * 10000)) where uid=<user_uid>;
```

Also I think you need to have the pin column be defined something like

```
pin int(4) zerofill not null
```

I would think.

Comment: I am try this code ,but it generate randomly  it also create 2 and 3 digits .

Answer (score 4):

I think something similar to SUBSTRING(FLOOR(RAND() * 9999 + 10000), 2) would do it?

Answer (score 3):

Is there a reason why you can't just do

```
UPDATE `users` set `pin`=FLOOR(10000*RAND());
```

?

Comment: I just didn't know how to do it. I ended up modifying your query a little and came up with this:
UPDATE `users` set `pin_code`= RPAD(FLOOR(10000*RAND()), 4, '0000');

Even though the field type is a smallint, this still works. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

> In my case I try to create random password for users ,here password is null

```
update users set password =(FLOOR(RAND() * 9999) + 10000)  where password is null;
```

> For your scenario

```
update users set pin =(FLOOR(RAND() * 9999) + 10000)  where pin is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help.

```
SELECT FLOOR ((RAND() * 10000));
```