# How do I auto generate a 4 digit pin SQL?

Tags: java, sql, mariadb, dao

Similar idea to this post:
[How do I generate a 4-digit pin no duplicating number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964624/how-do-i-create-a-random-4-digit-number-in-mysql)

However is there a way to do this automatically when a new user is created rather then setting them to random?

I'd like to be able to create a new user in my system and have their pin number automatically randomize a 4 digit number. Is AUTO_INCREMENT the only automatic option?

I have used this:

`UPDATE patrons SET pin=FLOOR(1000 + (RAND() *8999)) WHERE pin = ?`

However it's not what I want as it has to be done manually. I have created a method in my SQL DAO class in my Java program to do this after a user is created so it does work, but if I was to create a new user in Maria DB it would just do the auto increment by one value each time. I would prefer if the random generation would happen whichever way I use my database.

I'd greatly appreciate some help!

**Update**

I do not need the pin to be unique as the user will also need their library card number as well in order to log into the system.

Comment: Why must the PIN be unique? To be secure t should be truely random, which allows duplicates. Requiring uniqueness also makes the potential solution much more difficult and complicated.

Comment: @Bohemian I do not need it to be unique as the user will need their library card number to log in as well as the pin. I'm more so wondering if there is a way to make the random number automatically generate even when I create a new user in Maria DB as well as my java program or is this not possible?

Comment: Are you using Hibernate or JPA or SQL directly? What is the data type of the `pin` column?

Comment: @Bohemian The pin is of type 'int(4) zerofill not null default 0' in my database and in my java program it is a long (for a particular reason, but can change if doesn't suit). I am connecting to my database using the JDBC and in my SQL DAO class I have methods that query the database using regular MySQL queries. I'm not using Hibernate or JPA.

Answer (score 5):

4-digit PINs are **not supposed to be unique**, because users should be able change their PINs when they want, to whatever they want. Moreover, when there are more than 10'000 users, they **cannot be unique** (by pigeonhole principle).

Thus, this code:

```
UPDATE patrons SET pin=FLOOR(1000 + (RAND() *8999)) WHERE pin = ?
```

is **wrong**, because it will **change the PINs of all users** that share the same PIN, when **only one user decides to change the PIN**. The PIN should be changed for the user, and not for the number.

I would say: **random generation of default PIN**, with some provided entropy that would make the next PIN hard to guess, is the best. Auto-increment is bad for security reasons, and the standard random generators are bad for the same reason: the next PIN value is only slightly harder to guess than the increment. This should be different than **changing PIN by user request** — in this case the number provided by the user should be used.

PostgreSQL, for example, has `gen_random_bytes` for cryptographic-strength random generation. I suggest looking for something similar on your platform of choice.

Comment: not really an opinion ... it is more a verifiable fact

Answer (score 0):

Create a trigger the fires on insert:

```
create trigger client_pin
before insert on client
for each row set new.pin = 1000 + rand() * 9000;
```

See [live demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/q5TcLrFEe5UeyraqFg3quA/0) of below:

```
create table client (
  id int auto_increment primary key,
  name text not null,
  pin int(4)
);

create trigger client_pin
before insert on client
for each row set new.pin = 1000 + rand() * 9000;

insert into client (name) values ('Adam');
insert into client (name) values ('Betty');
```

---

It would be better if `pin` was calculated using `rand() * 10000` and you handled leading zeros with formatting, for example by selecting

```
lpad(pin, 4, '0') as pin
```

instead of selecting `pin` directly.